# GridSearchCV: Parameter error in XGBRegressor

Tags: python, xgboost, gridsearchcv

I use GridSearchCV to find the best parameter in my XGB model, here is my code

```
# Xgboost
grid_xgb = {
    'booster': 'gbtree',
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',
    'subsample': [0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9],
    'colsample_bytree': [0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9],
    'eta': [0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3],
    'max_depth': [3,5,7],
    'seed': [2021,2022],
    'eval_metric': 'logloss'
}

model_xgb = xgb.XGBRegressor()
search_xgb = GridSearchCV(estimator = model_xgb, 
                         param_grid = grid_xgb, 
                         cv = 5,
                         n_jobs = -1,
                         verbose = 2)
```

But I get an error information:

```
 Parameter values for parameter (booster) need to be a sequence(but not a string) or np.ndarray
```

I check the XGB document which says

"booster [default= gbtree ]

Which booster to use. Can be gbtree, gblinear or dart; gbtree and dart use tree based models while gblinear uses linear functions."

So, I don't know why the error happens and hwo to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) the different parameter values need to be passed to `GridSearchCV` as a list, which means that the `booster`, the `objective` and the `eval_metric` also need to be enclosed in square brackets:

```
grid_xgb = {
    'booster': ['gbtree'],
    'objective': ['binary:logistic'],
    'subsample': [0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9],
    'colsample_bytree': [0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9],
    'eta': [0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3],
    'max_depth': [3,5,7],
    'seed': [2021,2022],
    'eval_metric': ['logloss']
}
```